# java fileChooser disable features and options in main tool bar

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

JFileChooser - I want to disable some options in top tool bar - "Home" , "Up One Level" , "New Folder".
    in my code only "New Folder" works and it's disabled. I tried to use this methods on all buttons but it doesn't work, here is the code:

```
javax.swing.Action newFolder = fileChooser.getActionMap().get("New Folder");
newFolder.setEnabled(false);
javax.swing.Action home = fileChooser.getActionMap().get("Home");
home.setEnabled(false);
javax.swing.Action upOneLevel = fileChooser.getActionMap().get("Up One Level");
upOneLevel.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a brute force way based on the icon search, inspired from this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DisabletheJFileChoosersNewfolderbutton.htm) .

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    JFileChooser cho = new JFileChooser();

    disableButton(cho, "FileChooser.homeFolderIcon");
    disableButton(cho, "FileChooser.upFolderIcon");
    disableButton(cho, "FileChooser.newFolderIcon");

    cho.showOpenDialog(null);

}

public static void disableButton(final Container c, final String iconString) {
    int len = c.getComponentCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Component comp = c.getComponent(i);
        if (comp instanceof JButton) {
            JButton b = (JButton) comp;
            Icon icon = b.getIcon();
            if (icon != null
                    && icon == UIManager.getIcon(iconString)) {
                b.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } else if (comp instanceof Container) {
            disableButton((Container) comp, iconString);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a list of `UIManager` icons identifiers for `JFileChooser` :

> FileView.directoryIcon
>
> FileView.fileIcon
>
> FileView.computerIcon
>
> FileView.hardDriveIcon
>
> FileView.floppyDriveIcon
>
> FileChooser.newFolderIcon
>
> FileChooser.upFolderIcon
>
> FileChooser.homeFolderIcon
>
> FileChooser.detailsViewIcon
>
> FileChooser.listViewIcon

Comment: How many look and feels have you tested that on? How many platforms?  The problem is that this kind of solution tends to fall apart quickly

Comment: Maybe it is L&F related. For your actionMap approach, you should print the different keys in the map, in my case the key for going up one level is "Go Up". Unfortunately, I don't see any key in the map that would correspond to the Home button.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : I admit that I haven't tested this on another platform than my current one, along with the default L&F . If any answer we try to bring, need thorough testing upon any existing platform and any existing L&F , or any existing `Whateva`, no answer would be suggested...not any answer.

Comment: @Berger That's kind of my point, apart from developing your own look and feel delegate, there is no other "right" annswer

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Single Root File Chooser](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/single-root-file-chooser/) for a different approach.

It only allows the user to navigate directories below the specified directory. The "Up One" button is disabled. The "Home" button will take you back to the specified director.

You would still need to display the "New Folder" button.